# Strict typing in PHP

Tags: php, types

Can someone explain to me what this means in the PHP documentation? "*Function calls from within internal functions will not be affected by the strict_types statement.* ". With an example would be better, I think that's the only thing I didn't understand about strict typing.

Comment: It means calls from internal PHP functions to one of your functions (e.g. from `array_map`) will still ignore strict types, even if your function uses it. See the duplicate linked above.

Comment: thanks, I thought it applied to all internal PHP functions, but I've seen what kind of functions it really refers to.